# Create a MultipageEditor for XML

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, editor

I am working on an eclipse Plugin, and I would like to use an Editor, set some listeners on the current page(good terminology?), and remove these listeners when the user switches on another page (basically, the user is editing several files, as you could do with the default JAVA editor).

For the moment I have written a class extending StructuredTextEditor. The behavior of the plugin was the one expected, but when I try to work on several files, many problems occur. The main problem, according to me, is that I am not able to get notified when the user opens another page.

I read (and tested) a few things about MultiPageEditor, but it seems like it doesn't integrate an XML editor as default editor. How should I proceed in order to get a MultiPageEditor, with XML syntax coloring, and get notified when the user changes the current page to adjust my listeners ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The default Java editor does not edit multiple files. A separate copy of the editor is started for each file. The existing Eclipse WST XML editor uses a multipage editor to show different views on to a single XML file.

Comment: So I probably am in the case of the Java editor : an editor is started every time. But if I open 3 files, I have 3 editors open, and when I perform an action on one of them, the listeners from all the editors are triggered at the same time. This is something I don't really understand

Comment: Listener for text selection : ISelectionListener, and a listener when the editor is opened : IPartListener2

Comment: `IPartListener2` tells you about every part so you need to check what it is reporting. `ISelectionListener` with the selection service tells you about selections everywhere - this may not what you want.

Comment: You're right, that's definitely not what I would like to use. What would you suggest in this situation ? I need to be aware of the text selection (or simple click on the text) as soon as it happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110991/discussion-between-medal-and-greg-449).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your editor you can listen to selection changes in the editor text using:

```
getSelectionProvider().addSelectionChangedListener(listener);
```

where `listener` implements `ISelectionChangedListener`.

This applies to any editor derived from `AbstractTextEditor` (which includes `StructuredTextEditor`.

You need to do this fairly late in the editor creation. In the `createPartControl` method works:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent)
{
  super.createPartControl(parent);

  getSelectionProvider().addSelectionChangedListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: I am probably missing something, because this listener is never called for me. I tried several "selection" : simple click, double click, manual selection, but the method `selectionChanged` seems to be never called

Comment: Added a suggested location for adding the listener.

Comment: I might be quite annoying, but I can't find out where should I find a Composite object from my class extending StructuredTextEditor

Comment: This is an override of an existing method

Answer (score 2):

the code is not perfect but at least you will have an example of a MultiPageEditor integrating an XMLEditor: https://github.com/fusesource/fuseide/blob/8.0.0.Beta2/editor/plugins/org.fusesource.ide.camel.editor/src/org/fusesource/ide/camel/editor/CamelEditor.java

The idea is to call addPage(new StructuredTextEditor()) inside createPages() method.

regards,